# "You'll be hoping for a bit more from the new player, I suppose." Why the future continuous?

Tags: sentence, future, continuous-aspect, will-future, example

> “You'll be hoping for a bit more from the new player, I suppose.”

Why the future continuous?

Wouldn't one rather use the future simple instead? If not: why not?

Comment: _I am hoping for_ is a very common  usage implying that one is in a state of wishing for something desirable. I don't think there is any logical explanation of when we use _hope_ as opposed to _be hoping_.

Comment: Because hope springs eternal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope is a concept related to expectations and desires for the future, so most expressions of hope are about the future whenever present or future tense is used.  The statements "I hope for a bit more from the new player", "I am hoping for a bit more from the new player", "I will hope for a bit more from the new player" and "I'll be hoping for a bit more from the new player" technically have slightly different meanings, but in practice it is hard to imagine a situation where only some of them would be true. In this situation the choice of which statement to use is more a matter of style than of correctness.

Answer (score 2):

In this construction, the purpose of the progressive is to ensure that the question is not understood as a request; it 'softens' it, as it were.

**Discussion**

Here is a relevant section of [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (pp. 171-172):

> ***Will* + progressive**
>
> [22]  i  *When we get there, they'll probably still **be having** lunch.*       [aspectual meaning]
>          ii  *Will you **be going** to the shops this afternoon?*                                [special meaning]
>         iii  *When the meeting ends we'll **be flying** to Bonn.*                                       [ambiguous]
>
> In [i] we simply have the ordinary use of the progressive to express progressive aspectuality: the lunch will be still in progress at the time of our arrival. This is not how we interpret [ii], however. The meaning can best be seen by comparing it with the nonprogressive counterpart, *Will you go to the shops this afternoon?* The salient interpretation of the latter is as a request to you to go to the shops, and the role of the progressive in [ii] is to avoid such an interpretation. The progressive indicates that the matter has already been settled rather than being subject to decision now. Compare, similarly, *We won't buy any more* (interpretable as a refusal, made here and now) vs *We won't be buying any more* (following prior decision), or *Will he help us?* ("Is he willing?", decision still to be made) vs *Will he be helping us?* ("Has it been decided that he will?").
>
> The distinctness between the two meanings is seen clearly in the ambiguity of [22iii]. On the progressive aspectuality reading, we will already be flying to Bonn when the meeting ends; on the 'already decided future' interpretation, the *when* adjunct says when we will leave. The first is imperfective, with reference to a mid-interval; the second is perfective, just as in the non-progressive *we'll fly,* which, however, suggests that the decision is being made now. This use is particularly common with *will,* but it is also found with, for example, the idiom *be going,* as in *Are you going to be helping them again this year?* (where the non-progressive might again be construed as a request).

Comment: “You'll be hoping for a bit more from the new player, I suppose?” _is_ of course a request (for an answer) (it's not likely to be a rhetorical question), though it's a hedged/softened variation on “You're hoping for a bit more from the new player, I suppose?” and certainly on “You hope for / expect a bit more from the new player, I suppose?” The declarative-question construction avoids the "Will you do this, please?" default sense. As indeed  does using 'hope' instead of 'go/do/make ...' (*"Will you hope this, please./?").  I'd say the hedging effect is the more prevalent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, hedging is a good way of putting it (I used *soften*). As for it being a *request*, I meant it in the same sense in which the excerpt from CGEL meant it: an implied request not merely for an answer, but for undertaking the very action mentioned in the question.